# .NET Core SignalR: How to accomplish resource-based authorization?

Tags: .net-core, authorization, signalr, jwt

All my SignalR clients connect using a JWT bearer token. I utilize the `[Authorize]` attribute in my SignalR `Hub`.

This token contains a `userId` which can be used to check if a user has read access on the resource through the resource's `users` property which contains a `List<PuppyUserPermission>` that look like this:

```
public class PuppyUserPermission
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public bool read { get; set; }
    public bool write { get; set; }
}
```

The question is: how do I connect the dots here? Ideally, instead of something like

```
[Authorize]
public class PuppyHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendPuppy(Puppy pup)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(pup);
    }
}
```

I would so something like the following (this is more pseudo code than anything else, as I don't use valid methods):

```
[Authorize]
public class PuppyHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendPuppy(Puppy pup)
    {
        var clients = Puppy.users.Where(u => u.read == true);
        await clients.SendAsync(pup);
    }
}
```

Basically, I'd like to ensure that the clients recieving the `Puppy` object via SignalR would be authorized users on the resource. Problem is, `Clients` is just a list of `string` client IDs, and I'm not sure how to go about tying them to actual users on my `Puppy` resource.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the beginning, I had the feeling that the answer lay in [`IUserIdProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider), but I didn't see how that would work for multiple users.

I finally found the answer, but it'll definitely need some cleanup.

First, create your own implementation of `IUserIdProvider` as follows:

```
public class MyUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        var username = connection.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "THE_CLAIM_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_TO_IDENTIFY_USERS").First().Value;
        return username;
    }
}
```

Next, register it using DI:

`services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, MyUserIdProvider >();`

Now, when you want to send events from the server, use DI in your constructor to pull down an instance of your SignalR `Hub` as per usual:

```
 private IHubContext<PuppyHub> puppyHub { get; }
 public UsersController(IHubContext<PuppyHub> _puppyHub)
 {
     puppyHub = _puppyHub;
 }
```

Then, where when you want to tell your clients about the new `Puppy`:

```
// ... typical controller code
// assume we have a var, puppy, with a list of authorized users

// use System.Linq to get a list of userIds where the user is authorized to read the puppy
var authorizedUsers = (IReadOnlyList<string>)puppy.users.Where(x => x.permissions.read == true).Select(i => i._id).ToList();

// send the new puppy to the authorized users
await puppyHub.Clients.Users(authorizedUsers).SendAsync("SendPuppy", puppy);
```

And viola! You have now done resource-based authorization with SignalR.